# Accessing logged in user inside EJB?

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0

In a Java application, I need to obtain the logged-in user details inside an EJB3.

But sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() returns the value anonymous.

I tried to use JAAS (weblogic.security.auth.login.UsernamePasswordLoginModule) but still the Subject, Principal values are available only initially but are not getting transferred into the Business layer. And has the value anonymous instead.

My environment is Java / JSF / EJB3 / Weblogic 11g.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem many times. I put the user on a ThreadLocal and access it in the business layer. Either that or pass user as method parameter.